# Jquery Loading Overlay expands and contracts with window

Tags: jquery, overlay

I have a jquery Overlay over a div.  It works pretty well, except, when I expand and contract the window the overlay doesn't expand and contract with it.  It will expand and contract once I refresh the page, but It won't do it dynamically.  I have some code in there that I had hoped would solve the problem.  Unfortunately it did not.  Here is what I have currently...

```
function DemoSearchInternals()
{
    debugger;
    var form = $("#DemoGraphID");
    $div = $("#thatTable");
    //$loading = $('<img src="<%=Url.Content("~/images/ajax-loader.gif")%>" alt="loading" class="ui-loading-icon" style="display:none" id="img-load">');
    //$div.append($loading);
    var srlzdform = form.serialize();
    var PopID = <% =PopID %>;
    var options = [];
    var $url = $("#target").attr("action");
    $('<div id="overlay">').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        opacity: 0.2,
        top : $div.offset().top,
        left : $div.offset().left,
        width : $div.outerWidth(),
        height : $div.outerHeight(),
        background: 'blue url(<%=Url.Content("~/images/ajax-loader.gif")%>) no-repeat center'
    }).hide().appendTo('body');
    $(window).resize(function(){
    //$div = $("#thatTable");
    $('<div id="overlay">').css({
            top: $div.offset().top,
            left: $div.offset().left,
            width: $div.outerWidth(),
            height: $div.outerHeight()
        }).appendTo('body');
    });

    //$('div#TabView1').html('<div id="overlay"><img src="<%=Url.Content("~/images/ajax-loader.gif")%>" alt="loading" class="ui-loading-icon"></div>');
    //div.append('<img src="<%=Url.Content("~/images/ajax-loader.gif")%>" alt="loading" class="ui-loading-icon">');
    //$loading.show();

    $("#overlay").fadeIn();
    $.post('<%:Url.Action("SearchByDemographic", "PatientACO")%>', srlzdform, function (data)
    {
       DisplayDemographicSearch(data);
       $("#overlay").fadeOut();
    });
}
```

I will continue to peruse the internet to look for suggestions.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may slow down things a little on ie if you apply that to many elements, but I use the $(window).resize event when I need something to resize depending on the window size and it's threatening to become a headache.

Ex :

```
function setSize() {
    //Your code and everything affecting the resize depending on window width goes here
    //Exemple : 
    $("#mydiv").width($(window).width);
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    setSize();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

set a bottom and right, not a width and height in css (if the design allows). That will make the window keep the proper distances from the edges no matter what you have the design be.

If you want it to not get smaller than a certain size, make sure to put a min-height and min-width on the element too.